# Simpsons intro changes

Tags: alternate-version, the-simpsons, title-sequence

Does an intro exist from *The Simpsons* where Bart hits the uranium stick with his skateboard? Because I remember such a scene but can't find it. In the normal intro the uranium stick misses the skateboard. In the version that I am looking for Bart is hitting the uranium and it is flying away.

[image]
[image]

Comment: No such event mentioned at http://www.simpsonsarchive.com/guides/openings.list.html#bartskateboarding or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons_opening_sequence but of course that's not to say it never happened.

Comment: mhm ok I will look forward, it was one of my first Simpons episode I saw as I child.